# how to take xml data from url Using GET method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i need take XML data from 
this URL : http://45.119.203.114:8888/xmltv.php?username=epg&password=epg 
to parse EPG data

i have try with Javascript And PHP but it doesn't work

this my code

Javascript

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://45.119.203.114:8888/xmltv.php?username=epg&password=epg'); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.responseType = 'document';
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');

    xmlHttp.onload = function () {
        if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4  && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) {
            console.log(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send();
```

the result in my javascript code is always No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

and this my PHP code

```
$path = 'http://tvku.live:8888/xmltv.php?username=epg&password=epg';



    $xml=simplexml_load_file($path);
            $me = "sub-title";
            foreach($xml->programme as $item){
                echo "Start : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime(substr($item["start"], 0,  -6))) . '<br>';
                echo "End : " .date("G:i d.m.Y", strtotime(substr($item["stop"], 0,  -6))) . '<br>';
                echo "Channel : ".$item["channel"]. "<br>";
                echo "Title : ".$item->title. "<br>";
                echo "Info : ".$item->$me. "<br>";
                echo "Description : ".$item->desc. "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
```

there is no result in my php code, before in my PHP code i have try using CURL to get data but not that works too

please ask for your help, thanks

Comment: different domains, CORS problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the result in my javascript code is always No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Well, the error is pretty clear the backend is not allowed to answer to CORS request if you own the backend you have to allow CORS (take a look to [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) documentation).
Otherwise, you need to ask the backend owner to allow the CORS requests.